# creating custom PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer using property loaded dynamically

Tags: spring

I am facing some challenge creating PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer based on some value that is available in another property file.
I have a property file, custom-{environment}.property, which contains a value, that is needed to set location of PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.

My CustomConfiguration looks something like:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(customLocation);
    //Custom url location based on a String available in the properties file. This is the problem area
    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

I want to populate this `customLocation` from the properties file. Tried autowiring Environment, but it's failing as environment is null when `placeholderConfigurer()` is getting called. Tried using `@PropertySource("custom-${environment}.property")` and then `@Value("**customLocation**")`, but that's also not working.

Please let me know how this can be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say that adding a `ApplicationContextInitializer` to load the `custom-{environment}.properties` and afterwards loading the additional configuration file(s) is the easiests. You can just add a `PropertySource` that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding an [`ApplicationContextInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html) to load your property files instead of a plain `@PropertySource`. First load your  `custom-{environment}.properties` next your configurable properties file.

```
public class PropertySourceInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer {

    private static final String DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE = "classpath:custom-${environment}.properties";

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        final ConfigurableEnvironment env = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        final MutablePropertySources mps = env.getPropertySources();    
        //
        Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource(env.resolvePlaceholders(DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE));
        mps.addLast(new ResourcePropertySource(resource.getDescription(), resource));

        String additional = env.getProperty("name.of.property");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(additional) {
            Resource additionalResource = applicationContext.getResource(env.resolvePlaceholders(additional));
            if (additionalResource.isReadable() ) {
                mps.addLast(new ResourcePropertySource(resource.getDescription(), resource));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to get it to work with a `@PropertySource` will be much harder as the phases in which the `PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer` is created is different then the one in which the `@PropertySource` annotations are scanned. Staged loading of `@PropertySource` (which is basically what you want) is quite difficult. Spring Boot also has its own loading mechanism (which actually is also a `ApplicationContextInitializer`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. However, still have some problem. In my code, I have used a CustomPropertyPersister for parsing/persisting the additional property location. In PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer, I can set my persister for this kind of property. How can I use that persister in PropertySourceInitializer for the second propertysource?

Comment: Why would you need a `CustomPropertyPersister` in this case? I don't see that. You just retrieve the property from the already available propertysources.

Comment: CustomLocation that I used, is not a text or xml file. It's a CMS location. I would get the content from a url, but need to parse the relevant properties using custom persister, and load those separately. As far as I know, Spring DefaultPersister has properties and xml support only.

Comment: But that part wasn't in your question it mentions "another property file" not a separate non properties location/format. Not sure how complex it is but you can still create your own `PropertySource` that contains the logic of reading the properties (or just read them and add a `MapPropertySource`.

Comment: At last success. Thanks a lot for your help. I have used ContextInitializer for fetching the customLocation, and then used that in @Configuration in order to create PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer (where I set custom PropertyPersister to parse the custom location).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting your location as a system property?

```
@Value("#{ systemProperties['myapp.location'] }") 
private String location;
```

You need to set "myapp.location" as system property.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot. Currently, environment is in system property. However, custom location is available in a properties file, based on that environment.